# Artifact while streaming multicast with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Locally, from my windows machine with ffmpeg 3.3.2 from Zeranoe

> ffmpeg version 3.2.2 Copyright (c) 2003-2016 the FFmpeg developers
>   built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
>   configuration: --enable-gpl
>   --enable-version3 --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib

**Server side**

Launch udp multicast streaming.

```
 ffmpeg -re -i video.ts -an -f mpegts -c copy udp://224.1.1.1:5000
```

**Client side**

Playing with *ffplay* is correct, no artifacts displayed

```
ffplay udp://224.1.1.1:5000
```

Playing after decoding cause **artifacts**

```
ffmpeg -i udp://224.1.1.1:5000 -pix_fmt gray -f avi - | ffplay -
```

or

```
ffmpeg -f mpegts -i udp://224.1.1.1:5000 -pix_fmt gray -c:v rawvideo -f avi out.avi
```

Does someone has an explanation?

Comment: it's possible because ffmpeg has to "pass" it to ffplay that it "waits" so "misses" some packets.  Is ffplay on windows? Full output of ffmpeg -i ... please?

Comment: yes, ffplay and ffmpeg are on windows.

Comment: even if I do ffmpeg -f mpegts -i udp://224.1.1.1:5000 -pix_fmt y8 -c:v rawvideo -f avi out.avi, I have artifacts

Comment: Maybe ffplay just skips frames that are corrupted?  Also you may want an ffmpeg that has "udp + pthreads" or it won't buffer incoming udp packets in a separate thread...full output of ffmpeg -i udp... will help determine that. Cheers!

Comment: Do you know where I can find a windows ffmpeg version with "udp + pthread" ? because Zeranoe does provide that version. thx